# How to access invoked functions parameters from pytest_runtest_makereport

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

I'm trying to make custom pytest flag, which will store copy of result files when this flag is used. To do this, I need to access retroactively some other functions that were invoked during test run and pass in conftest their arguments, so based on that, my "store-copy-of-results-files function" should know what type of files it has to look for.

I managed to do that this way:

```
@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()

    if report.when == 'call':
    if STORE_REFERENCEDATA:
        acceptedFiles = call.excinfo.traceback[2].locals['expression']
```

By `traceback[2]` I can access function that was called before test run and get it's arguments. However, this works only if test fail, e.g. when regression files are missing or are different from actual results. But if test pass, I can't no longer access this arguments, because `excinfo` is empty.

Is it possible to do this in this way somehow, or do I need to do it differently?

Comment: why not use `reportlog`? -- https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-reportlog

Comment: @TeejayBruno not sure if this is exactly what I'm looking for. Basically, we are currently using `pytest-regtest` plugin, but for better customization and simplicity I'm trying to make our own scripts for regression tests of results and now I'm stuck on problem as described above, while trying to make similar functionality as `--regtest-reset` option - but in conftest. I'm new into pytest so many things are not very clear for me yet.

Comment: My mistake! I guess I'm having trouble trying to understand exactly what you're looking to accomplish. If the test is successful of course `excinfo` is empty because no exception occurred. If you can clarify what you're looking to store/save I'm happy to help further!

Comment: @TeejayBruno I'll try but please consider my low level of experience and understanding of pytest haha. So basically, we have set of regression tests, each for different operations of our software. Every test is calling some function from our library, based on what operation it tests. And here, in these functions there are variables with file types - different for every function. Then some other functions are called with these variables as input. I need to either preserve these variables, or somehow come back to them from conftest so my "reset files" function know what files to look for.

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to accomplish this without modifying the tests themselves?

Comment: @TeejayBruno Exactly, if it's possible, then tests should remain in the way they are now. I'm trying to make it so from perspective of writing or running tests there are as minimum of changes as possible. All other things, e.g. calling file comparison script etc., are called from functions from our library that I mentioned - here isn't limit for modifications, so I can create new functions or fixtures that will be helpful. Hope it make sense what I'm trying to describe.

Comment: I believe I understand what you're trying to do. In the simplest terms, you're seeking the ability to access variables present after the test execution. If so -- I have some ideas I think might work and will (hopefully!) reply with a solution in a bit.

Comment: @TeejayBruno Yes, I think that should help me to solve my problem. I would be very thankful if you could help me with ideas or examples how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same trouble as yours.

But now I fixed it through this code.

```py
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    report.case_name = str(item.funcargs['case_name'])
```

Hope this will help you.